Azure Runbook PowerShell Get AKS credentials issue
I facing issue which getting aks cluster credentials in Runbook. I am using Powershell for this.
My PowerShell Script,
Install-Module -Name Kubernetes -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser


Import-Module -Name Az
Import-Module -Name Az.Aks
Import-Module -Name Kubernetes



Connect-AzAccount -Identity
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "8ab15eb5-cd64-4b44-a934-8e798f6c13e1"

$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context

Kubectl get nodes

$kubeconfig = Get-AzAksCredential -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $aksClusterName -Admin

ERROR I am getting is ,

Please share your suggestion to achieve this.
Thank You

You can install the Az.Aks module in the runbook module option instead of Import-Module -Name Az.Aks and use the command Import-AzAksCredential to get the AKS credentials config instead of Get-AzAksCredential.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.aks/import-azakscredential?view=azps-12.0.0

The Get-AzAksCredential command is not valid for fetching AKS cluster credentials. Instead, you can use the command below:
Azure PowerShell :  Import-AzAksCredential
 Import-AzAksCredential -ResourceGroupName "Venkat" -Name "venkatakstest29"

Azure CLI: az aks get-credentials
 az aks get-credentials --name MyManagedCluster --resource-group MyResourceGroup

When I ran Get-AzAksCredential, I encountered the same error as below.

Make sure to check if the Az.Aks module is installed on the runbook.

If it is not installed, you can install the Az.AKS module by navigating to Modules > Add module > browse gallery.

Connect-AzAccount -Identity
Set-AzContext -Subscription "Subscription-Name"
$kubeconfig = Import-AzAksCredential -ResourceGroupName "Venkat" -Name "venkatakstest29" -Admin -Force
$kubeconfig
ls


Note: You need to assign the Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin Role to perform the action of listing cluster admin credentials.

Output:

